# TextAngular tab to leave field

Tags: tabs, textangular

I am using http://textangular.com/ but I need the tab to quickly move to the next field. Currently when the user presses tab it stays in the textangular field. How can I make the cursor move to the next field when tab is pressed?

[See punker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BfgVMwLGgLfeXoH2d9BQ?p=preview)

```
.
```

Answer (score 1):

In the minified or full version of text angular js file, search for 'TabKey' and remove that entire line.

https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/939